# Gromacs 4.6.1 Installation Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I am about to burst into tears now, since I am unable to get in touch with you guys. My problem is regarding the installation of gromacs 4.6.1, I followed exactly what was said in https://rohitnarurkar.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/gromacs-installation-for-linux-users/ I followed with success till the last one,but when I typed grompp, it showed error like Program grompp, VERSION 4.6.1 Source code file: /home/roshan2004/Downloads/gromacs-4.6.1/src/gmxlib/futil.c, line: 593

File input/output error: grompp.mdp For more information and tips for troubleshooting, please check the GROMACS website at http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Errors with some information about gromacs above, when I typed which mdrun Program mdrun, VERSION 4.6.1 Source code file: /home/roshan2004/Downloads/gromacs-4.6.1/src/gmxlib/gmxfio.c, line: 524

Can not open file: topol.tpr For more information and tips for troubleshooting, please check the GROMACS website at http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Errors So, clearly, there are some errors, Now, how to fix this ?
**I even tried to install by using sudo apt-get install gromacs , but then when I typed mdrun, it gave same problem as above - Can not open file:
topol.tpr
**
Even after installing via sudo apt, it gave me following problem: 
/usr/bin/mdrun
roshan2004@ubuntu:~$ mdrun
GROMACS:    gmx mdrun, VERSION 5.0.2

GROMACS is written by:
Emile Apol         Rossen Apostolov   Herman J.C. Berendsen Par Bjelkmar
Aldert van Buuren  Rudi van Drunen    Anton Feenstra     Sebastian Fritsch
Gerrit Groenhof    Christoph Junghans Peter Kasson       Carsten Kutzner
Per Larsson        Justin A. Lemkul   Magnus Lundborg    Pieter Meulenhoff
Erik Marklund      Teemu Murtola      Szilard Pall       Sander Pronk
Roland Schulz      Alexey Shvetsov    Michael Shirts     Alfons Sijbers
Peter Tieleman     Christian Wennberg Maarten Wolf
and the project leaders:
Mark Abraham, Berk Hess, Erik Lindahl, and David van der Spoel

Copyright (c) 1991-2000, University of Groningen, The Netherlands.
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, The GROMACS development team at
Uppsala University, Stockholm University and
the Royal Institute of Technology, Sweden.
check out http://www.gromacs.org for more information.

GROMACS is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

GROMACS:      gmx mdrun, VERSION 5.0.2
Executable:   /usr/bin/gmx
Library dir:  /usr/share/gromacs/top
Command line:
  mdrun

Back Off! I just backed up md.log to ./#md.log.2#

---

Program mdrun, VERSION 5.0.2
Source code file: /build/buildd/gromacs-5.0.2/src/gromacs/fileio/gmxfio.c, line: 513

Can not open file:
topol.tpr
For more information and tips for troubleshooting, please check the GROMACS
website at http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Errors

Comment: The installation was finished with `sudo apt-get install gromacs`. Everything else is off topic here. :(

Comment: I used sudo apt-get install gromacs , but still it gave me same problem

Comment: http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Tutorials

Comment: There is nothing in tutorials...I have already seen it